# Efficiently get the first record of a JSONL file

Tags: json, jq, jsonlines

Is it possible to efficiently get the first record of a [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/) file without consuming the entire stream / file? One way I have been able to inefficiently do so is the following:

> curl -s http://example.org/file.jsonl | jq -s '.[0]'

I realize that `head` could be used here to extract the first line, but assume that the file may not use a newline as the record separator and may simply be concatenated objects or arrays.

Comment: The JSONL specification requires: "Line Separator is '\n'"; thus if the file is JSONL as posited, using standard *ix tools such as `head` would be fine, unless of course you want the output to be pretty-printed. Be warned, though, that jq does not guarantee that numerical values are preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the JSONL format just returns a stream of JSON objects which jq handles quite nicely.  Best case scenario that you wanted the first item, you could just utilize the [`input`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input) filter to grab the first item.

I think you could just do this:

```
$ curl -s http://example.org/file.jsonl | jq -n 'input'
```

You need the null input `-n` to not process the input immediately then `input` just gets one input from the stream.  No need to go through the rest of the input stream.

Comment: Note that, if you want to _emit_ JSONL, jq has the -c flag which does that nicely.